# Perfect-MySQL majorVersion:3 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: perfect

I get an

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

error while building from terminal (swift build) (swift 4).
It points to a simple init in my code like:

```
let mysql = MySQL()
```

Two hints:

- Clue#1: I am not having any problem building in Xcode.  (Xcode 9)
- Clue#2: I have no problem building from terminal when using majorVersion:2

What may be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, putting this here if anyone else encounters the same problem:

I followed the example at : http://perfect.org/docs/MySQL.html and there it shows :

```
import MySQL
```

However, if change this to the following:

```
import PerfectMySQL
```

the build problem I mentioned above disappears.

I hope this helps somebody